# Excel Macro Change TextBox Color

Tags: vba, excel

I am attempting to write an Excel macro to change the color of at textbox automatically based on an input value from a cell in the sheet. The code that I currently have is:

```
Private Sub TextBox1_Change()

'Declare Variables
Dim cell As Range
Dim color As String

'Initialize Variables
Set cell = Range("A1")
color = cell.Value

'Set TextBox Color
If color = "" Then TextBox1.BackColor = RGB(255, 255, 255) 'white
If color = "1" Then TextBox1.BackColor = RGB(255, 0, 0) 'red
If color = "2" Then TextBox1.BackColor = RGB(0, 255, 0) 'green
If color = "3" Then TextBox1.BackColor = RGB(0, 0, 255) 'blue

End Sub
```

This is supposed to read a value from cell A1, then change the color of the textbox based on that value. My code does successfully change the color of the textbox, but it doesn't update until after I click into the textbox and type something. Is there a way to make the color update as soon as a value is entered into cell A1?

If it would be easier to do this with some other object I am not tied to a textbox but cannot just use a cell.

Comment: `not tied to a textbox` then conditional formatting for a cell?

Comment: That would be infinitely easier. Unfortunately a cell is one of the few things that I can't use. It needs to be some kind of excel object (ie. textbox, lable ect.).

Comment: Hmm maybe use `worksheet_change` event?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @findwindow suggested, you could use the `Worksheet_Change` event instead of the text-box event:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    'Declare Variables
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim color As String

    If Target.Address = Range("A1").Address Then
        'Initialize Variables
        Set cell = Range("A1")
        color = cell.Value

        'Set TextBox Color
        If color = "" Then TextBox1.BackColor = RGB(255, 255, 255) 'white
        If color = "1" Then TextBox1.BackColor = RGB(255, 0, 0) 'red
        If color = "2" Then TextBox1.BackColor = RGB(0, 255, 0) 'green
        If color = "3" Then TextBox1.BackColor = RGB(0, 0, 255) 'blue
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: You were probably writing this as I made my comment^^

Comment: @findwindow That I was, it is a fairly natural idea for any experienced VBA programmer -- but you did voice it first.

Comment: Well, commenting is faster than answering =P

Comment: couldn't it simple be `If Target.Address = "$A$1" Then`  and `color = target.Value` ? thus eliminating `Dim cell As Range`,  `Set cell = Range("A1")`

Comment: @user3598756 Yes, you are correct. I was making the code as similar to the original code as possible. It doesn't really make much difference though in the sense that in any case the code will execute before your finger is done leaving the enter key.

Comment: I agree on the speed. I put that in just as a contribution to the issue of having a code as lean as possible for a (possibly) easier and better maintenance of it. Also, `Select Case - End Select` block in lieu of all those `If- Then` clauses could be suggested

Comment: @drylkuch if this solved your problem, please mark the checkmark. Only you can do this.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I really appreciate it!